# Django - How to test this CBV?

Tags: python, django, testing, django-class-based-views

:)
I'm near the end of my first django "project".
I managed to make tests for everything, but one view.

I'm not really sure how and what to test here, does someone mind helping me out ?

```py
class CommentCreateView(CreateView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {'form': CommentForm()}
        return render(request, 'news/add_comment_to_article.html', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=kwargs.get('pk'))
            print(article)
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = article
            comment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('news:article', kwargs={'article_id': article.pk}))
        else:
            form = CommentForm()
            return render(request, 'news/add_comment_to_article.html', {'form': form})
```

Thanks for the help !!

Comment: What test do you mean?

Comment: Well I got tasked with making a "news site" app. I'm all done, and they want me to write a few tests for the app. I managed the rest, but Im not sure what to do and test here :/

I mean a regular unit test!

Comment: A view is not intrisically different from any other class (or function) and you test it the same way: for each important method, check that the nominal case returns the expected value and that the corner cases are properly handled.  You may want to check the [FineManual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/) for useful testing tools (request factory etc).